# Symfony 2 - Debug toolbar does not show ajax calls

Tags: symfony

I use jQuery to call ajax requests ($.post and $.ajax).

But the Symfony (2.7.7) Debug Toolbar does not show the requests.

[image: 0 Ajax requests]

Only if i open the profiler and view the last 10 requests i see the ajax call:

[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Symfony debug toolbar is skipping some ajax requests, it could be that the regex used to determine which ones is picking yours as well. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/base_js.html.twig#L207).

Comment: I don't define "excluded_ajax_paths". But if i do in config, the debug toolbar shows symfony internal ajax request but not my own ajax requests.